# Remove file before pollEnrich will end the strategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

If I delete file before when route will process exchange I get exception:
GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file. PollEnrich's strategy trying to move file from someFolder to someFolder/.camel.

```
from("wmq:queue:someQueue")//Here we get the message with information about the file
...//some logic
.pollEnrich("file:someFolder?fileName=someFile")
...//some logic
.choice()
    .when(...)//Here we compare checksum from message with checksum of the file
    .process(new SomeClassProcess)//And if they are different file will be deleted from someFolder
    .otherwise()
    .to(someAnotherFolder)
.end();
```

I'm trying to use .rollback("errorMessage")

```
onException(RollbackExchangeException.class)
.log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "SomeExcptn");

from("wmq:queue:someQueue")
    ...//some logic
    .pollEnrich("file:someFolder?fileName=someFile")
    ...//some logic
    .choice()
        .when(...)
        .process(new SomeClassProcess)//it will delete someFile from someFolder
        .rollback()
        .otherwise()
        .to(someAnotherFolder)
    .end();
```

But now I got garbage in application's logs - CamelExecutionException.
It works, but could you help solve it anower way?

P.S. I don't know do I need to delete file before I will provide URI to pollEnrich, thats why I don't use noop=true. In .otherwise() I need move file to .camel.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you do need to use any Processor to delete file. You could just do something like :

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;


@Before
public void before() {
    File outputDir = new File("transfer/outbox");
    File tmpDir = new File("transfer/tmp");
    for (File file : outputDir.listFiles())
        file.delete();
    for (File file : tmpDir.listFiles())
        file.delete();
}

@Override
public RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {

    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:transfer/inbox?noop=true")
                .to("file:transfer/tmp")
                .pollEnrich("file:transfer/tmp")
                .choice()
                  .when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).isEqualTo("Message1.txt"))
                    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${header[CamelFileName]} This file is discarded")
                  .otherwise()
                    .to("file:transfer/outbox")
                .end();
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void smokeTest() throws Exception {

    NotifyBuilder notifyBuilder = new NotifyBuilder(context)
        .wereSentTo("file:transfer/outbox").whenDone(1)//Just to make the test enough time to complete
        .create();

    notifyBuilder.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    File inputDur = new File("transfer/inbox/");
    assertEquals(inputDur.listFiles().length, 2); // Message1.txt, Message2.txt (no .camel because ?noop=true)

    File outputDir = new File("transfer/outbox/");
    assertEquals(outputDir.listFiles().length, 1); // Message2.txt

    File tmpDir = new File("transfer/tmp/");
    assertEquals(tmpDir.listFiles().length, 1); // .camel


}
```

or if you don't care about logging it yourself, a more proper way would be to use a Message Filter instead of a Content Based Router :

```
from("file:/path/to/your/file")
  .filter(somePredicate)
  .to("file:/where/you/want/it/to/move")
```

Deleting a file while camel use it in a in-flight exchange is **not something to do**, camel does lock the file with another file suffiexed by a .camelLock to prevent other routes to consume him, but modifying this file with a processor is not safe at all.

Additionnaly, I don't see any ?noop=true in your example. If you want to delete or move the file, using ?noop is no relevant.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
I have added information to the question, I hope that is now enougth to explain what I try to achieve =)

In your first example file will remain in sourceFolder, but I need to delete it if verification of checksum will be failed.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but the first example I posted would work, I've edited my initial answer with an actual test I made.